# SQL function that returns significant figures as varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I'm trying to modify a SQL function [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920933/round-to-n-significant-figures-in-sql) back in 2009. The function returns a float, but I need the trailing zeros as well. For example with 2 significant figures:

```
2153.012 -> "2200"
123.361 -> "120"
12.331 -> "12"
1.014 -> "1.0"
0.804 -> "0.80"
0.0011 -> "0.0011"
0.001 -> "0.0010"
```

EDIT: I should not have assumed people were familiar with significant figures (apologies). It's a simple way of distinguishing when 0s are place holders or values.

For numbers less than 1, the 0s immediately after the decimal are place holders, but trailing 0s are values. So, `0.0010` indicates that the zero after the 1 is a real value. With 3 sig figs, the number would need to be written as `0.00100`.

For numbers larger than 1, it’s not always obvious without knowing the number of sig figs. For example, are the zeros in 2000 place holders or values?

EDIT2: Some more examples (upon request).

**Large numbers**

| Measured | 1 Sig Fig | 2 Sig Figs | 3 Sig Figs | 4 Sig Figs | 5 Sig Figs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 80125.01255 | 80000 | 80000 | 80100 | 80130 | 80125 |
| 8012.01255 | 8000 | 8000 | 8010 | 8012 | 8012.0 |
| 801.012555 | 800 | 800 | 8.01 | 801.0 | 801.01 |
| 80.01255 | 80 | 80 | 80.0 | 80.01 | 80.013 |
| 8.01255 | 8 | 8.0 | 8.01 | 8.013 | 8.0126 |

**Small numbers**

| Measured | 1 Sig Fig | 2 Sig Figs | 3 Sig Figs | 4 Sig Figs | 5 Sig Figs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.100362 | 0.1 | 0.10 | 0.100 | 0.1004 | 0.10036 |
| 0.010362 | 0.01 | 0.010 | 0.0104 | 0.01036 | 0.010362 |
| 0.001036 | 0.001 | 0.0010 | 0.00104 | 0.001036 | 0.0010360 |
| 0.000103 | 0.0001 | 0.00010 | 0.000103 | 0.0001030 | 0.00010300 |
| 0.000010 | 0.00001 | 0.000010 | 0.0000100 | 0.00001000 | 0.000010000 |
| 0.000001 | 0.000001 | 0.0000010 | 0.00000100 | 0.000001000 | 0.0000010000 |

The function I'm modifying is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION RoundSigFig(@Number float, @Figures int)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Answer float;

    SET @Answer = (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN intPower IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE FLOOR(fltNumber * POWER(CAST(10 AS float), intPower) +0.5) 
            *POWER(CAST(10 AS float), -intPower)
        END AS ans
    FROM (
        SELECT
            @Number AS fltNumber,
            CASE WHEN @Number > 0
                THEN -((CEILING(LOG10(@Number)) -@Figures))
            WHEN @Number< 0
                THEN -((FLOOR(LOG10(@Number)) -@Figures))
            ELSE NULL END AS intPower       
        ) t
    );

    RETURN @Answer;
END
```

It works as advertised. To get the output as varchar, I've attempted the use the `FORMAT` function and a bunch of `CASE` expressions to pad out the needed zeros, but never managed to get it to work.

Comment: Please show what you tried. I would imagine you need `RETURNS varchar(20)` and something like `RETURN CONVERT(varchar(20), @Answer, 2);` or similar

Comment: Please show use what you mean by "**need the trailing zeros as well**" e.g. `2153.012 -> "2200.00"` i.e. you want to add 2 zeros? and `0.0011 -> "0.001100"` ??? it's really not clear what you are asking for

Comment: Believe I have have found a solution. & I opted to add another answer so comments will be "in context".

Comment: I'm curious why you need to do that in SQL? Surely whatever app you consume this data with can resolve that for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question calls for a very specific style of numeric formatting, references for this are [columbia.edu 1](https://ccnmtl.columbia.edu/projects/mmt/frontiers/web/chapter_5/6665.html) and [columbia.edu 2](https://ccnmtl.columbia.edu/projects/mmt/frontiers/web/chapter_5/6664.html)

The first part of answering was to verify the existing function (`LimitSigFigs`) from 2009 (link in the question). This does work but I believe there is a simpler equivalent (`LimitSigFigsv1`). I also believe that it is beneficial to retain a function that will return a float (e.g. for use in ordering results) so either of these functions may be used in the subsequent formating.

As it turns out both of the numeric functions do most of the "heavy lifting" and in the main all one needs to do is force that output into a string, which can be done via the format function (nb: I tried str() and it simply did not work as well as format does). However the special formatting specified requires some additional zeros to small numbers that require some special handling. This is done by inspecing the length of the string and the position of the first non-zero digit after the decimal point. This determines if additional zeros are required, how many are reqired, and then appends those if needed.

In the end (after many iterations) the formatting function is quite simple (which is nice!) and hopefully will perform reasnably well. Note, I opted to prepare a second function that "passes thru" the parameters into the existing numeric function for simplicity. Also note user defined scalar functions are not known for their performance - but they are convenient.

The following is a simplified function to round to a significant number, you may use this or the original, but note I haven't done very extensive testing with either.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LimitSigFigsV1](@value FLOAT, @sigFigs INT) RETURNS FLOAT AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @result FLOAT
  IF (@sigFigs < 1)
    SET @result = NULL
  ELSE
    SET @result = CASE WHEN @value = 0 THEN 0 
                       ELSE ROUND(@value, @sigFigs - 1 - FLOOR(LOG10(ABS(@value)))) 
                  END
  RETURN @result
END
```

- takes a floating point number value and an integer sigFigs as inputs.
- returns a floating point number rounded to the specified number of significant figures.
- If the sigFigs input is less than 1, return NULL.
- If the value input is 0, return 0.
- Otherwise, round the value to the specified number of significant figures using the ROUND function
- then returns the rounded value.

Then the final formating is conducted through this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FormatSigFigsV2(@Number FLOAT, @Figures INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(200) AS 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(200); 
  SET @Result = FORMAT(dbo.LimitSigFigsv1(@Number, @Figures),'0.################'); 

  /* Count the number of significant digits */
  DECLARE @SigFigs INT = 0;
  DECLARE @i INT = 1;
  WHILE @i <= LEN(@Result) AND @SigFigs < @Figures
  BEGIN
    IF SUBSTRING(@Result, @i, 1) BETWEEN '1' AND '9'
      SET @SigFigs = @SigFigs + 1;
    SET @i = @i + 1;
  END

  /* Add trailing zeros if necessary */
  IF CHARINDEX('.', @Result) > 0 AND @SigFigs < @Figures
    SET @Result = @Result + REPLICATE('0', @Figures - @SigFigs);
  ELSE IF CHARINDEX('.', @Result) = 0 AND @SigFigs < @Figures
    SET @Result = @Result + '.' + REPLICATE('0', @Figures - @SigFigs);

  RETURN @Result; 
END
```

- first calls another function called dbo.LimitSigFigsv1 to limit the number of significant figures in the input number to the specified number of figures
- then counts the number of significant digits in the result by iterating over each character in the string and checking if it is a non-zero digit
- If the result contains a decimal point and the number of significant digits is less than the specified number of figures,  adds trailing zeros after the decimal point
- Or, if the result does not contain a decimal point and the number of significant digits is less than the specified number of figures,  adds a decimal point followed by trailing zeros

Note limited testing has been undertaken, using the following table within the range of 1 to 5 for the significant number. (ps: I changed the inital test set from (say) 80125.01255 to 87125.112550 to reduce confusion with the number and placement of zeros).

The remainder of this answer replicates the details of a fiddle site, hopefully this will allow you to follow the tests conducted and how the functions are used.

```
CREATE TABLE measurements (
  value decimal(24,8)
);

INSERT INTO measurements (value)
VALUES
  (87125.112550),  (8712.112550),  (871.112550),  (87.112550),  (8.112550),
  (0.111362),  (0.011362),  (0.001136),  (0.000113),  (0.000011),  (0.000001)
  , (1.2), (1.4), (1.8564), (1.98765)
  ,(100000),(9000),(100),(90),(10),(9), (0);
```

```
22 rows affected
```

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LimitSigFigsV1](@value FLOAT, @sigFigs INT) RETURNS FLOAT AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @result FLOAT
  IF (@sigFigs < 1)
    SET @result = NULL
  ELSE
    SET @result = CASE WHEN @value = 0 THEN 0 
                       ELSE ROUND(@value, @sigFigs - 1 - FLOOR(LOG10(ABS(@value)))) 
                  END
  RETURN @result
END
```

```
/* while loop logic */
CREATE FUNCTION FormatSigFigsV2(@Number FLOAT, @Figures INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(200) AS 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(200); 
  SET @Result = FORMAT(dbo.LimitSigFigsv1(@Number, @Figures),'0.################'); 

  /* Count the number of significant digits */
  DECLARE @SigFigs INT = 0;
  DECLARE @i INT = 1;
  WHILE @i <= LEN(@Result) AND @SigFigs < @Figures
  BEGIN
    IF SUBSTRING(@Result, @i, 1) BETWEEN '1' AND '9'
      SET @SigFigs = @SigFigs + 1;
    SET @i = @i + 1;
  END

  /* Add trailing zeros if necessary */
  IF CHARINDEX('.', @Result) > 0 AND @SigFigs < @Figures
    SET @Result = @Result + REPLICATE('0', @Figures - @SigFigs);
  ELSE IF CHARINDEX('.', @Result) = 0 AND @SigFigs < @Figures
    SET @Result = @Result + '.' + REPLICATE('0', @Figures - @SigFigs);

  RETURN @Result; 
END
```

```
SELECT 
    value AS Measured,
    dbo.FormatSigFigsV2(value, 1) AS Sig_1a,
    dbo.FormatSigFigsV2(value, 2) AS Sig_2a,
    dbo.FormatSigFigsV2(value, 3) AS Sig_3a,
    dbo.FormatSigFigsV2(value, 4) AS Sig_4a,
    dbo.FormatSigFigsV2(value, 5) AS Sig_5a
FROM measurements;
```

| Measured | Sig_1a | Sig_2a | Sig_3a | Sig_4a | Sig_5a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 87125.11255000 | 90000 | 87000 | 87100 | 87130 | 87125 |
| 8712.11255000 | 9000 | 8700 | 8710 | 8712 | 8712.1 |
| 871.11255000 | 900 | 870 | 871 | 871.1 | 871.11 |
| 87.11255000 | 90 | 87 | 87.1 | 87.11 | 87.113 |
| 8.11255000 | 8 | 8.1 | 8.11 | 8.113 | 8.1126 |
| 0.11136200 | 0.1 | 0.11 | 0.111 | 0.1114 | 0.11136 |
| 0.01136200 | 0.01 | 0.011 | 0.0114 | 0.01136 | 0.011362 |
| 0.00113600 | 0.001 | 0.0011 | 0.00114 | 0.001136 | 0.0011360 |
| 0.00011300 | 0.0001 | 0.00011 | 0.000113 | 0.0001130 | 0.00011300 |
| 0.00001100 | 0.00001 | 0.000011 | 0.0000110 | 0.00001100 | 0.000011000 |
| 0.00000100 | 0.000001 | 0.0000010 | 0.00000100 | 0.000001000 | 0.0000010000 |
| 1.20000000 | 1 | 1.2 | 1.20 | 1.200 | 1.2000 |
| 1.40000000 | 1 | 1.4 | 1.40 | 1.400 | 1.4000 |
| 1.85640000 | 2 | 1.9 | 1.86 | 1.856 | 1.8564 |
| 1.98765000 | 2 | 2.0 | 1.99 | 1.988 | 1.9876 |
| 100000.00000000 | 100000 | 100000.0 | 100000.00 | 100000.000 | 100000.0000 |
| 9000.00000000 | 9000 | 9000.0 | 9000.00 | 9000.000 | 9000.0000 |
| 100.00000000 | 100 | 100.0 | 100.00 | 100.000 | 100.0000 |
| 90.00000000 | 90 | 90.0 | 90.00 | 90.000 | 90.0000 |
| 10.00000000 | 10 | 10.0 | 10.00 | 10.000 | 10.0000 |
| 9.00000000 | 9 | 9.0 | 9.00 | 9.000 | 9.0000 |
| 0.00000000 | 0.0 | 0.00 | 0.000 | 0.0000 | 0.00000 |

```
/*
+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
|   Measured    | 1 Sig Fig | 2 Sig Figs | 3 Sig Figs | 4 Sig Figs  |  5 Sig Figs  |
+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| 87125.01255   | 90000     | 87000      | 87100      | 87130       | 87125        |
| 8712.01255    | 9000      | 8700       | 8710       | 8712        | 8712.0       |
| 871.012555    | 900       | 870        | 871        | 871.0       | 871.01       |
| 87.01255      | 90        | 87         | 87.0       | 87.01       | 87.013       |
| 8.01255       | 8         | 8.0        | 8.01       | 8.013       | 8.0126       |
| 0.100362      | 0.1       | 0.10       | 0.100      | 0.1004      | 0.10036      |
| 0.010362      | 0.01      | 0.010      | 0.0103     | 0.01036     | 0.010362     |
| 0.001036      | 0.001     | 0.0010     | 0.00104    | 0.001036    | 0.0010360    |
| 0.000103      | 0.0001    | 0.00010    | 0.000103   | 0.0001030   | 0.00010300   |
| 0.000010      | 0.00001   | 0.000010   | 0.0000100  | 0.00001000  | 0.000010000  |
| 0.000001      | 0.000001  | 0.0000010  | 0.00000100 | 0.000001000 | 0.0000010000 |
+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+--------------+
*/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8NbHVxFC)

Comment: I have amended the formatting function so that integers are given a decimal point when this is needed (when zeros are appended). & Test cases include 1000, 900, 100, 90, 10, 9 and zero (not sure if zero is handled correctly btw).

Comment: Sorry, been doing my actual job. Wow, looks great. Tested it on hundreds of numbers - all good, even zero. Amazing. One minor oddity is decimal numbers  between 1-10 ( i.e. `1.2`), It  is correct for 2 sf, but off by 1 zero for 3 sf, 4 sf, etc. That is `2sf: 1.2 --> 1.2 (ok)`, but `3sf: 1.2 --> 1.2 (?)`, `4sf: 1.2 --> 1.20 (?)`. Numbers <1 and > 10 work perfectly.  Seriously, it's all good - you've done enough. I typically only use 2 sf and I'll simply ignore that oddity.

Comment: Are you using the most recent code? have a look at these results https://dbfiddle.uk/Ww5KruU5 is there any error in those results? If not, please ensure you use the most recnt function code nb: there are 2 variants, you can choose whichever you prefer (I prefer the one *without* the small while loop)

Comment: If you look at the fiddle output again for `1.2` for Sig_2 and Sig_3 , you'll notice you got the same result as me - both are `1.2`.

Comment: OK - so now I am going to use the former "alternative logic" because it is correct (I believe) for all test cases so far (**but I am still unsure about what zero should do**). This means I have **changed the function** - and there is only 1 variant now - take note. I have changed the answer to match the **new function**.  If further questions arise, please verify you are now using the "while loop" based function.

Comment: I will give it another go - you're awesome (obviously). As for zero, it doesn't really matter (seriously). If you want, you could give it the same sf as passed to the function (i.e. 0.00 for 2 sf) or just 0. Zero is never reported as a numerical value, but as something like "not detected...yada, yada".

Comment: Hi Paul, I ran hundreds of numbers thru the functions. Perfect!. Fantastic, thank you.!

Comment: Fabulous! Thanks for the confirmation (and challenge, which I  enjoyed).